# Is there a shorthand notation for initialising associative arrays or objects in PHP, like the one introduced to JavaScript with ES2015?

Tags: php, notation, shorthand

With ES2015, [a shorthand notation for object initialisation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) was introduced to JS in the form of

```js
let a = 'foo', b = 'bar', c = 'baz';
let o = {a, b, c};

// result:
{ a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "baz" }
```

I wonder if there's something similar in PHP7, so that if I had the variables `$a`, `$b`, and `$c`, I'd get an associative array with the keys corresponding to the variable names and the values to their values:

```php
$a = 'foo'; $b = 'bar'; $c = 'baz';
// $o = ????

// expected result equal to
array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c)
```

Comment: Well the function [`compact`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)  exists … But I don’t think there’s any shorthand syntax that would help you do away with the function call.

Comment: `array_combine()`?

Comment: `compact('a', 'b', 'c')` - that's great! Feel free to post it as an answer, @04FS!

Comment: Feel free to accept Aksen’s answer, not that much point in adding a second one now that says the same thing :-)

Comment: Very gracious of you, thank you for hinting at `compact()`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you did it in JS, you can collect all variables by their names in array and do [compact()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php):

```
$a = 'foo'; $b = 'bar'; $c = 'baz';

$ar=['a','b','c'];
print_r(compact($ar));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => foo
    [b] => bar
    [c] => baz
)
```

Or just do `compact('a', 'b', 'c');` as well.

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Aj5ga)**

Comment: Thanks for the hint at `compact()`. I prefer the even shorter notation `compact('a', 'b', 'c')` - you could add that to your answer as well.

Comment: @ConstantinGroß, sure, you can use it in that way also. It's my own behaviour - to cache variables for further using)

Comment: I think you forgot the `compact` statement in the first part of your answer :) Guess you meant `$ar = compact(['a', 'b', 'c']);`.

Comment: @Jeto, see Demo, it is in `print_r()`

Comment: @AksenP Sure, but it should be there in the answer too then, cause if you don't click the demo link it seems like `$ar=['a','b','c'];` would magically produce that output you shared right below ;)

Comment: @Jeto, ok, you've got you wanted.